# Can't install pandas on termux

Tags: termux

I want to install pandas on Termux. I have tried so many methods but I am getting this error:

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [307 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=61.0.0
        Using cached setuptools-67.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.33
        Using cached Cython-0.29.35-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
      Collecting versioneer[toml]
        Using cached versioneer-0.28-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.23.2 (from oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16)
        Using cached numpy-1.23.2.tar.gz (10.7 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): still running...
        Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [274 lines of output]
            setup.py:71: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.23.2 may not yet support Python 3.11.
              warnings.warn(
            Running from numpy source directory.
            setup.py:86: DeprecationWarning:

              `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
              of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
              Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
              It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
              For more details, see:
                https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html


              import numpy.distutils.command.sdist
            Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
            Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
            Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
            Cythonizing sources
            INFO: blas_opt_info:
            INFO: blas_armpl_info:
            INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
            INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: blas_mkl_info:
            INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: blis_info:
            INFO:   libraries blis not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
            INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
            INFO:
            INFO: openblas_info:
```

What should I do to install it?
Help me, please

Comment: You are trying to install an Python application that has been developed for an older Python 3.x version on latest Python 3.11. Use an older Python version or try to use a newer python library like numpy v1.24.3 (which hopefully supports Python 3.11).

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. If I'm right in reading the error, then the issue is probably [related to Cython](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/12412#issuecomment-1281112505). You might have to install Cython first. Otherwise, [use a compiled package from the TUR repository](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/3225#issuecomment-1519025860).

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks very much bro.

Comment: You're welcome! If you managed to solve the issue, feel free to post an answer describing what you did to solve it!

Comment: I ran this commands one by one and I was able to install pandas ""1st command: pkg i tur-repo
2nd command: pkg update
3rd command: pkg i python-pandas""